# Record audio stream via rtsp from IP camera [C#]

Tags: c#, audio, streaming, rtsp

Im new to this forum (as registered user) and trying to figure out how to properly get an audio stream from an IP camera via rtsp protocol and transfer it e.g directly to byte array.
It should be real time so I want to avoid creating any audio files or so.
I've found Ozeki SDK but it's shareware.
My project is only for academical purposes. 
Of course Im not looking for exact solution, just for some proper library which could contain features to handle this issue.
Thank you very much for any answer in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack, read our guidlines for posting as this post does not meet our guidlines. We do not recommend 3rd party libraries also this question is too broad and opinionated

Comment: But look at OpenCV

Comment: Thank you for answer. If you mean that, that I didnt include any fragment of code, then it is because Im looking for a tool (library) which could offer functionality Im seeking for. 
I will look at OpenCV, thanks!